# SQLiteDatabase through NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public class DatabaseHundler {

    Context context;
    private static DatabaseHundler instance;
    private static helper help;
    public DatabaseHundler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static DatabaseHundler getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new DatabaseHundler(context);
        }

        if(help == null)
        {
            help = instance.new helper();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private synchronized static SQLiteDatabase open()
    {
        try{

            return help.getWritableDatabase();
            /*switch(mode) {
            case WRITE_MODE:
                    return db.getWritableDatabase();
            case READ_MODE:
                    return db.getReadableDatabase();
            default:
                    return db.getWritableDatabase();
            }*/
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private class helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        public helper() {
            super(context, Constants.Database_Name, null, Integer.parseInt(Constants.Database_Version));
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public boolean CreateTableMyData(String query)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHundler.open();
        if(db != null)
        {
            db.execSQL(query);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Cursor GetUserData(String tableName)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHundler.open();
        if(db != null)
        {
            Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            try{
                if(cursor != null)
                {
                    if(cursor.getCount() >0)
                    {
                        return cursor;
                    }

                }
            }catch(Exception e){

            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public Cursor GetData(String tablename ,String colname , String val)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHundler.open();
        if(db != null)
        {
            String query = "Select * from "+tablename+" where "+colname+" =? ";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{ val});

            //Cursor cursor = db.query(tablename, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            try{
                if(cursor != null)
                {
                    if(cursor.getCount() >0)
                    {
                        return cursor;
                    }

                }
            }catch(Exception e){

            }

        }
        return null;

    }

    public boolean SaveUserData(ContentValues values , String tablename)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase dataBase = DatabaseHundler.open();
        try{


                if(dataBase != null)
                {
                    if (values!= null)
                    {
                        dataBase.insertWithOnConflict(tablename, BaseColumns._ID, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

        }catch(Exception e){}
        return false;
    }

    public boolean DeleteData(String tablename)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = DatabaseHundler.open();
        try{
            if(database != null)
            {
                database.delete(tablename, null, null);
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and exception is

```
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714): Process: com.joyia.PriceFinder, PID: 15714
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joyia.PriceFinder/com.joyia.PriceFinder.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:256)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at com.joyia.PriceFinder.DatabaseHundler$helper.<init>(DatabaseHundler.java:52)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at com.joyia.PriceFinder.DatabaseHundler.getInstance(DatabaseHundler.java:30)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at com.joyia.PriceFinder.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:9)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at com.joyia.PriceFinder.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:34)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-30 11:24:20.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):    ... 11 more
```

////////splash activity

```
public class Splash extends Activity
{
    static String DeviceId;
    static String Key;
    static String Email;
    static String  Version;
    static String status;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        new Controller();


        Register register = Controller.hundler.retriveRegisterData();

         TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        DeviceId =   telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        Key= Utility.KeyGenration(DeviceId);
        try {
            Version = "v"+getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(register == null)
        {
            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            dialog.setMessage("Enter Email here");
            LayoutInflater inflate = this.getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            dialog.setView(view);
            dialog.show();
            final EditText email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Button ok = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Email = email.getText().toString();
                     RefrashTask task = new RefrashTask();
                     task.execute();
                     dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

////////////////Controller Class where we make database hundler

```
public class Controller extends Application
{
    public static DatabaseHundler hundler ;
    public Controller() {
        hundler = DatabaseHundler.getInstance(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your Splash class.

Comment: @Ahmad Give us the code where you are trying to make instance of the database or trying to open it.

Comment: Why are you calling application class from your Activity ? Have you defined your `Controller` class as application in your manifest ? Application class will be always launched first then after activity will be launched.

Comment: what this function retriveRegisterData() do? where is the code?

Comment: thanks a lot @GrIsHu my issue resovle  my mistake is this i make object of controller in Acitivity and not define in menifest file

Answer (score 2):

The context you passed to the database handler wasn't a valid context.

`Controller` is-a `Application` but in your activity `onCreate()` you initialize it with `new`. That's a no-no. You should initialize your `Application` class by declaring it in your manifest. You can use an `Application` as a `Context` in `onCreate()` but not earlier e.g. in a constructor.